# Will Mr. Mado return in Tokyo Ghoul Re?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

So, I noticed in the opening for Tokyo Ghoul Re that they showed Kureo Mado wearing a hood, so does this mean he will return? Surely even he wasn't so deceitful and cunning that he would fake his death, go behind the CCG's back, and hunt ghouls while undercover. They also showed a hooded figure holding Amon's doujima quinque, and while they didn't show his face, I'm hoping this was him.

Answer (score 1):

> In the opening for Tokyo Ghoul Re that they showed Kureo Mado wearing a hood

You are mistaken, the guy wearing black hoodie in the OP theme is

> **Seidou Takizawa**. At the end of the Owl Suppression Operation, he faced Tatara together with Koutarou Amon and was subsequently reported dead by the CCG.

---

As per the story in the anime, Mado was declared dead by the CCG (season 1 episode 8). Not sure if he would make an appearance in *Tokyo Ghoul :Re*.

According to manga

> Kureo Mado is dead. He didn't make any appearance after that event, so there's no doubt that he's dead. You can also confirm from the [wiki](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Kureo_Mado)

Comment: sorry, I'm having trouble uploading the screenshot of him, but that's really a face you can't mistake. However, since I'm having trouble with the picture, I'll give you the next best thing: the link to the video and the exact moment he popped up.

Comment: https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Py24xhrpeNs

Comment: 1:00-1:03(he literally pops up for three seconds, but they show his face, and as I mentioned before, he's not exactly someone you can mistake for someone else)

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying, I have updated my answer!